# Foreach com esse tipo de JSON (PHP)

Tags: php, json, foreach

Estou tentando exibir os valores de um JSON com PHP mais sem exito. Código Usado:

JSON:

```
{
    "event_name": "offline_message",
    "widget_id": "sEcXk3TXEw",
    "visitor": {
        "name": "ARTULITO BARBOSA DE SOUSA",
        "email": "artulito-barbosa@bol.com.br",
        "phone": "11-952896992",
        "number": 15070,
        "chats_count": 1
    },
    "offline_message_id": 767,
    "message": "<Message text is not displayed here>",
    "session": {
        "geoip": {
            "region_code": "27",
            "country_code": "BR",
            "country": "Brazil",
            "region": "Sao Paulo",
            "city": "São Paulo",
            "isp": "",
            "latitude": "-23.4733",
            "longitude": "-46.6658",
            "organization": "NET Virtua"
        },
        "utm": null,
        "ip_addr": "201.6.231.89",
        "user_agent": "Mozilla\/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit\/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome\/58.0.3029.110 Safari\/537.36"
    }
}
```

---

**Preciso obter apenas os dados dos campos:**

- event_name
- visitor->name
- visitor->email
- visitor->phone
- session->geoip->region
- session->geoip->city
- session->geoip->latitude
- session->geoip-> longitude

---

Estava tentando algo no PHP parecido com isso

```
<?php

$url = 'https://admin.jivosite.com/widgets/webhooks-log/721441/1';
$content = file_get_contents($url);
$json = json_decode($content, TRUE);

foreach($json['visitor'] as $item) {
    print $item['name'][0];

}

?>
```

O link com toda a lista que estou tentando ler: https://admin.jivosite.com/widgets/webhooks-log/721441/1

Comment: Você já verificou se em `$content` está chegando corretamente os dados do JSON? Pois aparentemente a página indicada exige autenticação e com apenas a função `file_get_contents` você não consegue fazer essa autenticação.

Comment: **Não tem como responder essa pergunta**, pois o código apresentado parece atuar sobre uma estrutura de dados diferente do fragmento de  estrutura apresentada na pergunta e o link para estrutura de dados completa não está acessível. Recomendo o fechamento e remoção da pergunta dada o fato da pergunta ser de 2017 e nada ter sido feito a respeito.

Comment: Outro detalhe: seu `json_decode` está passando o argumento `$assoc` como `true`, ou seja, o JSON será decodificado para um array associativo e não para um objeto.

Answer (score -1):

O json_decode neste caso irá retornar somente arrays associativos pois todo json está com chave {
Não há no json o colchete [.
Neste caso não encontrará um elemento com índice 0 em nenhum nó do json.

```
event_name vai ser $json['event_name']
visitor->name vai ser $json['visitor']['name ']
...
session->geoip->region vai ser $json['session']['geoip']['region']
...
```

Comment: Então se eu receber isso via post (webhooks) ficaria dessa forma?!

`$request = file_get_contents("php://input");
$output = json_decode($request, true);
$name = $output['visitor']['name'];
$email = $output['visitor']['email'];
$phone = $output['visitor']['phone'];
$city = $output['session']['geoip']['city'];`